# Send js object into html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to fill an hidden field of my html form with an object from JS.
This is my form

```
<form id="form_infos">
    <label for="title">Titre:</label><input type="text" name="title" id="title_input"/>
    <input id="event" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
</form>
```

Js side

```
element.click(function() {
    $("#title_input").attr({value :event.title});
    $("#event").attr({value :event});
});
```

This js part is minimized, but as you can see, event is an object with many field such as title. I could get all the field one by one. But they are too many of them and I need to have the full object.

The issue is, doing this, I'm only getting the string `[object Object]` into my var event when I treat the form and not the object himself.

Thanks for help.

PS: I can't use JSON.stringify on event because I have circular references.

Comment: We need to see your `event` object to help you

Comment: If you want to store multiple fields in one, you'll have to serialize somehow, as a form field cannot store complex data like an object. The browser you are using is converting the event object into a string, which result in the `[object Object]`. If you say you can't use `JSON.stringify` because of circular references, try to get rid of those for data-submission. (Using IDs to identify child objects, rather than to include them directly)

Comment: I think is not possible. You just can get some field in the `event object` .

Comment: Actually I found a function to stringify whith circular references; https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js
I can now get my all objet into Json; I should be able to build it again after if no fields are missing i guess.